# Mysql query/order of operations

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to figure out this task:

List all details of each stallion if the colour information is not null or not empty.

Table:

[image]

The following doesn't seem to work, I keep on getting information on the mares as well:

```
SELECT * FROM horse
WHERE (gender='S')  
AND colour IS NOT NULL
or NOT colour='';
```

I thought that the parenthesis meant that `gender='S'` would "trigger" first, but I guess I'm misunderstanding order of operations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. First, `and` has a higher precedence than `or`, so your `where` clause is in fact interpreted as if it were `((gender='S') AND colour IS NOT NULL) or (NOT colour='')`. Second, even if you had the parentheses correctly, `(colour IS NOT NULL NOT colour='')` is always true - if `color` is `null` it's not equal to `''`, and if it's `''`, it's not `null`. So, actually, you just need a series of `and` conditions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   horse
WHERE  gender='S' AND 
       colour IS NOT NULL AND
       colour != '';
```